# Find string in any column to get row number that matches condition

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Most questions here are related to finding a pattern like string in a specific column and do something with it. But what if I don't know the column?
Link to Q/A for a specific column: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

I try to compare two dataframes, to make sure that they match, no columns have been added or rows deleted. One of those files is like a template. Where a group stands for a value range.

**An example:**

```
template = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Headline': ['Subheading', '', 'Animal', 'Tiger', 'Bird', 'Lion'],
         'Headline2': ['', 'Weight', 2017, 'group1', 'group2', 'group3'],
         'Headline3': ['', '', 2018, 'group1', 'group2', 'group3']
         })

testfile = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Headline': ['Subheading', '', 'Animal', 'Tiger', 'Bird', 'Lion'],
         'Headline2': ['', 'Weight', 2017, 150, 15, 201],
         'Headline3': ['', '', 2018, 152, 12, 198]
         })

     Headline Headline2 Headline3
0  Subheading                    
1                Weight          
2      Animal      2017      2018
3       Tiger    group1    group1
4        Bird    group2    group2
5        Lion    group3    group3

     Headline Headline2 Headline3
0  Subheading                    
1                Weight          
2      Animal      2017      2018
3       Tiger       150       152
4        Bird        15        12
5        Lion       201       198
```

If I would do this `print((template == testfile).all().all())`, it would be `False`.

As a human, I know that row three to five differs, so I want to exclude them from my comparison:

```
drop_r = [3, 4, 5]
template = template.drop(template.index[drop_r])
testfile = testfile.drop(testfile.index[drop_r])
```

Then I would get `print((template == testfile).all().all())` is `True`

So how can I get all row numbers into the object `drop_r` for the condition that a row contains group[n].

I need to find the rows in template where the substring 'group' appears in any of the columns?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @Alex: I changed the example a bit, because I thought that it would be clear enough. Now my request should be clearer.

Comment: Your question is still a bit confusing. Do you need to find the rows where `testfile != template` or do you need to find the rows in template where the substring `'group'` appears in any of the columns?

Comment: @ALollz: Maybe it is because of the heat. Your last suggestion: I need to find the rows in template where the substring 'group' appears in any of the columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if `'group'` is found anywhere in the DataFrame you can stack it, check if anything contains `'group'` and then get the indices.

```
import numpy as np

ids = np.unique(template.stack()[template.astype('str').stack().str.contains('group')].index.get_level_values(0))
#array([3, 4, 5], dtype=int64)
```

To see the bad rows:

```
template.reindex(ids)
#  Headline Headline2 Headline3
#3    Tiger    group1    group1
#4     Bird    group2    group2
#5     Lion    group3    group3
```

To see the good rows:

```
template[~template.index.isin(ids)]
#     Headline Headline2 Headline3
#0  Subheading                    
#1                Weight          
#2      Animal      2017      2018
```

Comment: wow, that's even better. I found out this solution by myself, but yours is a lot better: Define groups `drop_r = ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']` and show the dataframe without those groups `testfile.loc[~template.isin(drop_r).any(axis=1)]`. My solution would need a list of familiar groups. Thank you!